# How to integrate branch.io to application if my manifest file has a pre-existing android:name?

Tags: android, branch.io

In the integration guide, it is said to configure the manifest file by adding

```
 <application`
    android:name="io.branch.referral.BranchApp"
    .
    .
    .
 </application>
```

However, my application already overrides the application class by using android:name in manifest. What should I do now to integrate branch.io to my application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your Application class just adding in the `onCreate()` method:

```
// Branch logging for debugging
Branch.enableDebugMode();

// Branch object initialization
Branch.getAutoInstance(this);
```

More [info here](https://docs.branch.io/apps/android/#load-branch).

Comment: I tried this, it gives the Branch API Error in logcat

Comment: Logcat: 2019-08-11 10:23:04.445 4379-4718/com.smm.smm I/BranchSDK: posting to https://api.branch.io/v1/install
    2019-08-11 10:23:04.446 4379-4718/com.smm.smm I/BranchSDK: Post value = {"Removed due to Privacy"}
    2019-08-11 10:23:04.754 4379-4718/com.smm.smm I/BranchSDK: returned {
    2019-08-11 10:23:04.754 4379-4718/com.smm.smm I/BranchRemoteInterfaceUrlConnection: JSON exception: End of input at character 1 of {
    2019-08-11 10:23:04.755 4379-4379/com.smm.smm I/BranchSDK: Branch API Error: Conflicting resource error code from API

Comment: @CSLearner This is some separate problem. It has nothing to do with your question. You may wish to consider asking a separate question